# Is NUnit Setup attribute a code smell?

Tags: c#, nunit

I have written a set of NUnit classes, which have Setup and TearDown attributes.  Then I read this: http://jamesnewkirk.typepad.com/posts/2007/09/why-you-should-.html.  I can understand what the author is saying where you have to scroll up and scroll down when reading the Unit Tests.  However, I also see the benefit of Setup and TearDown.  For example, in a recent test class I did this:

```
private Product1 _product1;
private Product2 _product2;
private IList<Product> _products;

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    _product1 = new Product();
    _product2 = new Product();
    _product = new List<Product>();
    _products.Add(_product1);
    _products.Add(_product2);
}
```

Here `_product1`,  `_product2` and `_products` is used by every test.  Therefore it seems to violate DRY to put them in every method.  Should they be put in every test method?

Comment: This is primarily opinion based. It more or less depends on your preference.

Comment: To me, these attributes appear to perform approximately the same purpose as constructor and dispose methods. IMO this question is somewhat subjective...

Comment: I've taken the approach you showed in your example before, and sometimes I tell myself that is a bad idea and create the items under test within each test.  Surely arguing with yourself about something is a clear sign that it is very much opinion based, and also that I am rather capricious

Comment: If `_product1` and `_product2` are used in every test why don't you create base class with its own `SetUp` and do it there?

Comment: @Guy, what is the point in that?

Comment: @w0051977 You will have this code only in one place instead of in every test. The base `SetUp` will be executed before the test `SetUp`. But this is only good if *all* the tests need this.

Comment: @Guy, if I only have the code above in one TestClass.  if I was using the code in many TestClasses then I think your approach would be good i.e. base class.

Comment: @w0051977 You did wrote *is used by every test*...

Comment: @Guy, I meant every test in one test class.  Apologies.

Answer (score 2):

This question is very subjective, but I don't believe it is a code smell. The example in the linked blog post was very arbitrary and did not use the variables setup in every test. If you look at your code and you are not using the variables from the `SetUp`, then yes, it is probably a code smell.

If your tests are grouped well however, then each test fixture will be testing a group of functionality that often needs the same setup. In this case, the DRY principle wins out in my books. James argued in his post that he needed to look in three methods to see the state of the data, but I would counter that too much setup code in a test method obscures the purpose of the test.

Copying setup code like you have in your example also makes your tests harder to maintain. If your `Product` class changes in the future and requires additional construction, then you will need to change it in every test, not in one place. Adding that much setup code to each test method would also make your test class very long and hard to scan.

Comment: Thanks.  That is what I thought.  Can you confirm that it is "acceptable" to declare variables as I have done in the Setup? I have always done it like that.  I am trying to follow the principle of least astonishment these days.

Comment: One can easily use the gist of that article and use setup methods. If you have to glance at the setup method when writing the test, you've done something wrong, but if you can rely on the instances you require to be there, you've done it right. For instance, if I need to test a service, which depends on additional services, setting up the mocks and the service under test in the setup method is a good idea. Feeding it with data for the test, however, is not. In other words, if your test relies upon a bank account with money in it, set up the account in setup, put money in it in the test.

Comment: Many of my tests are the same and if you look at NUnit's test suites, we follow the same pattern. It is very hard to tell from your `SetUp` how you use those products, so it is impossible to tell without looking at your entire test fixture. We don't even know what you are testing :)

Comment: "If your tests are grouped well" says it all. :-)